# How to run calculations on sum of two columns?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In the `Invoice` class of my Rails application I need to find all invoices that are overdue.

I have only two database columns, `date` (which is a type `datetime` field) and `days_allowed` (which is a type `integer` field).

This is what I've got:

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.overdue
    where("date + days_allowed < ?", Date.today)
  end

end
```

It's neither throwing an error nor returning the relation that I need, though.

Is there a better way to sum two database columns and then do calculations on it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: show the SQL of this AR query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are database-specific sql hackery that could do this, and other answers have suggested, I would do this a different way...  You are interested in an attribute called "date_due", but that attribute doesn't exist.  I'd make it.

- Add a migration that adds an invoice_due_on field to your table
- in your model add a before_save hook, something like this:

```
    before_save :calculate_due_date

    def calculate_due_date
      invoice_due_on = your_other_date + days_allowed.days
    end
```

- do something to trigger all the existing invoices to get them to save, updating the new field.  for instance, from a console:

```
    Invoice.all.each do |i|
      i.save
    end
```

This answer relies on some date magic given to you in Rails by the ActiveSupport gem.  With ActiveSupport, you can do all kinds of date math, like:

```
    4.days.from_now
    my_birthday - 7.days
```

and so on.  Thats what the 'days_allowed.days' method does above.

Comment: OK, thanks. I will mark your answer as the correct one because this is pretty much what I ended up doing. Unfortunately, I got stuck again and posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21367195/how-to-run-a-callback-function-on-two-attributes-that-depend-on-each-other). Today is one of those days...

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what type of database adapter you're using with ActiveRecord; for example, using PostgreSQL, you can add an INTERVAL to any DATETIME (aka TIMESTAMP), which uses a pretty natural syntax. 
`TIMESTAMP '2014-01-26' + INTERVAL '3 days' = TIMESTAMP '2014-01-29'`
However, SQL itself has a `DATEADD()` function you could certainly use. What database are you using?

And here's a [PostgreSQL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Working_with_Dates_and_Times_in_PostgreSQL#2._You_may_add_or_subtract_an_INTERVAL_to_a_TIMESTAMP_to_produce_another_TIMESTAMP) wiki link for more information.

Comment: I am using SQLite right now but may be moving to Postgres later, so cross-database compatibility is important.

Comment: Postgres doesn't support `DATEADD()`, and MySQL I believe uses DATE_ADD, not to mention if you change to a different RDBMS that isn't SQL-based, or a NoSQL database. So while using pure SQL queries will certainly be the fastest (at scale), perhaps you should consider doing the arithmetic in ruby instead, if cross-database compatibility is more important to you.

Comment: OK, thanks for your help but how exactly can I do that in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot if you're using mysql:

```
def self.overdue
  where("DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL days_allowed DAY) < ?", Date.today)
end
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work unfortunately. I must admit that I am using SQLite, though.

Comment: Do you have different days_allowed per column? If not, there's a much easier way of doing it =)