# How to run a callback function on two attributes that depend on each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Rails app I have an `Invoice` model with the attributes `date` and `due_date`.

For reasons of simplicity I don't want the user to manually enter the `due_date` but rather simply enter the **number of days** that should be added to the `date`.

This is why I set up a virtual attribute `days_allowed`.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  before_save :save_date

  attr_accessor :days_allowed

  def days_allowed # attribute reader (I need that too!)
    (due_date - date).to_i
  end

  def save_date
    self.due_date = date + days_allowed.days
  end

end
```

However, when a user picks a date in the form and enters a number of days, e.g. `10`, I get wrong results because the `save_date` callback refers to the `days_allowed` method rather than the attribute of the same name.

The key problem seems to be that I am using the callback on two different attributes that depend on each other (`date` and `days_allowed`).

Can anybody tell me how to solve this puzzle?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: try changing `self.due_date = date + days_allowed.days` to `self.due_date = date + @days_allowed.days`, use the instance variable instead of the getter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach (no `before_save` is necessary):

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user

  def days_allowed
    (due_date - date).to_i
  end

  def days_allowed=(days)
    self.due_date = date + days
  end
end
```

**EDIT** Not supposed to work with mass assignment when both `date` and `days_allowed` are present unless `date` always goes first.

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense too. It works pretty well when updating `invoices`, however when trying to save a **new** record I get this error: `undefined method '+' for nil:NilClass`. I find that strange because I am instantiating `date` to `Date.today` in my controller `new` action already.

Comment: It doesn't work, in fact even for update as it depends on the order of attributes. If `days_allowed` is the last one in params hash it will work, but there is no good way to control it. Why not make `due_date` a virtual parameter and store `days_allowed`? Do you need to modify `due_date` too?

Comment: I need to run a database query on `due_date` in another place of my app. That's why I need a database column. I used to store `days_allowed` in the database instead of `due_date`. However, that got me into trouble when running large queries on the database. Have a look at my [other question from today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21362013/how-to-run-calculations-on-sum-of-two-columns).

Comment: Then I would suggest storing both `days_allowed` as "normal" attribute (which you can use in forms), and `due_date` computed in `before_save` hook. Just keep in mind that `due_date` is only valid after saving and you are not supposed to change it manually as it will break `days_allowed`. And changing `days_allowed` will break `due_date` until save. Chicken and egg problem, one of attributes should be limited in rights.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping to avoid a third database field but I think you are probably right. It's the only way to solve the chicken and egg problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to store all three fields, just not provide any form attributes for editing the calculated one.

While your use-case at it is might seem like this is a violation of 'don't repeat yourself', I think this is an instance of coincidental duplication.  Let me explain:

Consider your next problem - you are going to start having due dates on weekends, holidays, etc.  For exactly that reason I wrote the business_time gem:

https://github.com/bokmann/business_time

so in your solution where you add 10 days, you can now add 10 business days.  The exact due date can now fluctuate across weekends, 3-day weekends created by holidays, etc.  And if you have to deal with snow days, like most of the East Coast of the U.S. has had to lately, you can just add tham as a holiday and recalculate.  The number of business days is still 10, but the due date has changed.  The number of business days was a critical piece of data to save, not a piece of data to calculate.  The due data needs to be saved, because its a piece of information calculated in a context that you'll want to save for querying rather than try to recalculate every time.